# Ruby Time object for midnight UTC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time, utc

I need to be able to create UTC Time objects in Rails, but no matter what I try it ends up being a local Time object *converted* to UTC.

**application.rb**

```
config.time_zone = "UTC"
```

**Examples**
I try to create a Time object for midnight on New Years 2017:

```
Time.new(year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

*=> 2017-03-01 00:00:00 -0500*

```
Time.new(year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0).in_time_zone
```

*=> Wed, 01 Mar 2017 05:00:00 UTC +00:00*

```
Time.new(year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0).in_time_zone('UTC')
```

*=> Wed, 01 Mar 2017 05:00:00 UTC +00:00*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
Time.utc(year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

or just

```
Time.utc(year, month, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the following might do what you want:

```
Time.new(year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0, "+00:00")
```

See [the documentation for more details.](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Time.html#class-Time-label-Creating+a+new+Time+instance)